# How to check if TCP buffer is full

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

I've got myself a little game where you connect to a homemade C# dedicated server with TCP sockets. In both Unity Editor, Standalone Windows build and Unity Remote on my phone, my game works well and my packets are fully acknowledged by the server and all the clients. Things get dirty with an Android build on my phone.

I can start the game, create a new game room on lobby and run the game room when I'm ready. But in game, I cannot move as expected. At first, i thought it was my player controller, but it was not. Here's what's happening:

the game see the touch input and send it over network ;

the server receive the packet, can read it, understand it and broadcast his answer (if valid) to any client connected ;

Case 1 : the client won't receive anything (the OnReceive method is not even called) on my async connection (99% of what's happening)

Case 2 : the client receive the packet, understand it and apply the according behavior in game -> the player moves (with custom threaded A* pathfinding on a grid). This case occurs very rarely.

guess the receive buffer is full.

I wonder if it's not the android network system that goes to some kind of sleep mode. I saw that it could happen, but I don't know how to resolve this or if it's related to my problem.

Today, I don't understand why, theorically, this behavior occurs and how to fix it. If someone have any clues, I'll be very grateful to hear it.

Thank you guys

Answer (score 0):

Before sending try to check if socket can write aka buffer is not full

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.socket.poll?view=netframework-4.7.2